# MSSQL: How to display TOP 10 items from GROUP BY query?

Tags: sql, count, group-by, subquery

I have a query which displays this as result:

```
Year-Month  SN_NAME Raised Incidents
2015-11 A   14494
2015-11 B   8432
2015-11 D   5496
2015-11 G   4778
2015-11 H   4554
2015-11 C   4203
2015-11 X   3477
.......+ thousands more rows for 2015-11
2015-12 A   3373
2015-12 B   3322
2015-12 H   2814
2015-12 D   2745
......+ thousands more rows for 2015-12
......+ thousands more rows for 2016-01 - 2016-10
2016-11 B   2645
2016-11 C   2571
2016-11 E   2475
2016-11 D   2466
....+ thousands more rows for 2016-11
```

I need to select TOP 10 SN_NAME by Raised_Incident count from last month and and then show their COUNTS for previous 12 months.

The query I use to display above result is this one:

```
DECLARE @startOfCurrentMonth DATETIME
SET @startOfCurrentMonth = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)

SELECT 
    CONVERT(char(7),IM.SN_SYS_CREATED_ON,121) as "Year-Month"
    ,CI.SN_NAME
    ,COUNT(IM.SN_NUMBER) as "Raised Incidents"
FROM [dbo].[tab_IM_Incident] IM 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tab_SNOW_CMDB_CI] CI on IM.SN_CMDB_CI = CI.SN_SYS_ID
WHERE 
    IM.SN_SYS_CREATED_ON >= DATEADD(month, -13, @startOfCurrentMonth) AND    IM.SN_SYS_CREATED_ON < @startOfCurrentMonth
    AND (IM.SN_U_SUB_STATE <> 'Cancelled' OR IM.SN_U_SUB_STATE IS NULL)
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(char(7),IM.SN_SYS_CREATED_ON,121)
    , CI.SN_NAME
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(char(7),IM.SN_SYS_CREATED_ON,121) 
    , COUNT(IM.SN_NUMBER) DESC
```

The problem is I don't know how to limit each month values to TOP10 only, as the query returns me around 200 000 rows in total, while it should return 13x10 = 130 rows.

The expected output is exactly as on top of the question, but limited to only top 10 rows per month for last 13 months.

Please advise.

Comment: Put the expected output in the form of table. Works better than words

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Lots of non-ANSI SQL there...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the 10 incidents that are top for the most recent month, and then to see their incidents for all months in the data.

Here is one method:

```
with t as (
      your query here
     )
select t.*
from (select top 10 t.*
      from t
      order by YearMonth desc, RaisedIncidents desc
     ) top10 left join
     t
     on t.sn_name = top10.sn_name
order by YearMonth desc, RaisedIncidents desc;
```

Note that the `top 10` is not filtering on the latest month.  Instead, it orders by the latest month and then `RaisedIncidents`.  This assumes that there are at least 10 incidents in the most recent month.

Comment: With small adjustments to colum names and ";" after setting my variable it works like a charm! Thank you Gordon.